# How to build a class-based decorator of a class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

```py
class Taggable:
    TAG_ATTR_NAME = "_taggable_tag"

    @staticmethod
    def GetTag(target) -> str:
        if not hasattr(target,Taggable.TAG_ATTR_NAME):
            raise Exception(f"Object is not tagged")
        return getattr(target,Taggable.TAG_ATTR_NAME)

    def __init__(self, tag :str = "default_tag"):
        self.tag = tag

    def __call__(self,cls :type):

        orig_new = cls.__new__
        def my_new():
            instance = orig_new(cls)
            setattr(instance, Taggable.TAG_ATTR_NAME, self.tag)
            return instance

        if not isinstance(cls,type):
            raise Exception(f"Decorator {type(self).__name__} applied to value {repr(cls)} of type {type(cls).__name__}")

        cls.__new__ = my_new()
        return cls


@Taggable
class A:
    def __init__(self,fa :str):
        self.fa = fa
        print(f"__init__ called on A with fa={self.fa}, tagged as {Taggable.GetTag(self)}")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, fa: str, fb: str):
        super().__init__(fa)
        self.fb = fb
        print(f"__init__ called on B with fb={self.fb}")


b: B = B("aaa","bbb")
print(Taggable.GetTag(b))
```

Running this on python 3.6 gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/$user/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 35, in <module>
    class B(A):
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Looking around the web there seems to be little to no authoritative documentation on how class decorator classes are initialized and called by the interpreter and what arguments are passed to their dunder methods